Add syntax highlighting for the c++ tag
Please add syntax highlighting to the c++ tag.
From What is syntax highlighting and how does it work? :

Only moderators can change the highlighting language for a tag.

lang-cpp is one of the supported languages for syntax highlighting.

I have reviewed this and it should be fixed. I looked at it on one question and syntax highlighting for cpp now works.
